# Random Color loop using ChartJs and loops

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript issue using chartJs and a loop
I am trying to get a different color for each database_set rendered but for some reason it render the same color each time

Here is my code if you can have a look please ;)

```
function getRandomColor() {
      var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
      var color = '#';
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;

var datasetValue = [];
for (var j=0; j<team_member_count; j++) {
    datasetValue[j] = {
        backgroundColor: getRandomColor,
        label : name[j],
        data : info_data,
    };
}
var looped_data = datasetValue


var info_process = new Chart(ctx2,{
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: labels_info,
    datasets: looped_data
        },
    options: {
       scale: {display: true,
               ticks: {
                 beginAtZero: true,
 }
              },
       responsive:true,
       maintainAspectRatio: true,
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backgroundColor property should be assigned some kind of string.  You're assigning it a function.

I think you want the string result of calling the function instead.

So this:

`backgroundColor: getRandomColor,`

Should probably be:

`backgroundColor: getRandomColor(),`